# Square root of 2, need x digits after the dot

Tags: c++, c

Tried everything an I can't get an idea how to do it. I'm new at programming, trying to manage c and c++ languages, but sometimes I stuck at zero. Can anyone help me with this? I need to get X digits after squared of 2. Sounds easy but it isn't for me. Thanks for ya attention.
And this is an idea

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double a = 2;
    double b = 1;//somehow i read about dividing, and square of 2 is between 1 and 2;
    double c = (a-b*b)/(2*b);
    double d = b+c;
    double c1= (a-d*d)/(2*d);
    double d1 = c1+d;
printf("%.16f\n%.16f\n",d1, d);

}
```

Comment: Try learning one language at a time. Get a book about one and start from there.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Show what code you have, any what the issue is in the code.

Comment: What range can X take? Is it a compile-time constant or a run-time variable? sqrt(2) is about 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317667973799 ... just truncate it.

Comment: While a solution for C can work in C++, the opposite isn't necessarily true. Please be specific, which language do you want to learn?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: i'm moving more on c language, forgot to mention it. The thing is that I understant what those things .3f or smth like that do, but after~16 numbers after the dot, it throws zeros. My task is to do a program that can show more than that. Do I need some kind of math algorythms to change it into program ?

Comment: For the format strings, [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might come in handy. As for the zeroes, while `double` has higher precision than `float`, it's not as much as `long double`, and even `long double` have a finite and fixed precision. You might want to check into a multiple-precision library such as [libgmp](https://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Anything stopping you from simply printing X numbers after the dot?

Like so:
(for plain c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (void)
{
double myRoot = sqrt(2.00);
printf("%.3f\n", myRoot);
return 0;
}
```

a double is a number with accuracy beyond whole numbers. the `sqrt()` function returns a double and takes input of type double. Its a c standart function whose definition is included in the header file `math.h`. the `%3.f` in the `printf()` call says it should print the number with 3 places behind the dot.

Its worth noting that c and c++ are entirely different languages, so you need to choose which one you want to tackle.

Comment: i'm moving more on c language, forgot to mention it. The thing is that I understant what those things .3f or smth like that do, but after~16 numbers after the dot, it throws zeros. My task is to do a program that can show more than that. Do I need some kind of math algorythms to change it into program ?

Comment: @Andrelis ~16 places is then where the double precision ends. A data type double can only save so many numbers after the dot. There is a limit to how precise it can get. Its also worth noting that there are some results who cannot be accurately displayed in double, `sqrt(2)` is a good example. Those are rounded to the nearest representable number in the data type.

Comment: So is it possible somehow take this number into array with all of its digits?

Comment: Not by using the c library function `sqrt()` because that uses a return type double, and, as such, is bound to the precision limits of double. Now if you implement your own algorhitm function that saves the results in an array instead, that could work, but is out of scope for the question here. Its additionally worth noting that `sqrt(2)` is an irrational number, and thus cannot ever be represented just using decimal numbers. It has an infinite amount of numbers after the dot.

Comment: and if i need to bring around 200 numbers after the dot, array won't help me?

Comment: @Andrelis it will, but you will have to implement sqrt() yourself, with your specific constraints in mind. There are some algorhitms out there for approximating N numbers after the dot for irrational square root results, but you will have to implement that yourself. You can theorethically write your own function that stores the result in an array with 100 elements, or 200 elements, or even 500 elements.

Comment: Ahhh this sound harder with every word you say. Too much to learn so far.

Comment: @Andrelis sometimes it gets overwhelming, but there is alot of documentation out there and tutorials on almost everything. Google is your best friend in learning programming soon and properly. :)

Comment: the worst thing that I have  days to make this program.. Thats the wors thing

Comment: @Andrelis If you look for specific constants, for instance directly for sqrt(2), you can use a Taylor Series Expansion Algo to approximate (We're moving in upper level calculus here). An example of how its done is here: http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Programs/programs.html

In any event, I recommend you find a way using ordinary advanced calculus and related maths to solve your problem, and then translate that way into code, rather then starting from the other side. Math and programming are closely related.

Comment: ohhh gosh, hard to understant this things in this program... I have a clue how mathimaticaly count this square, but the problem is how to turn it into code... ahhh, Somehow, somehow...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double number = 20.0;
    double sq = sqrt(number);
    printf("%.3lf\n", sq);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works for me. 
The .3 in the print statement says it is 3 digits

Answer (score 0):

if you want to round off your actual number, you can do `floor(val*pow(10, X))/pow(10,X)` but it is probably neater to only print it in a given precision:
[c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) or [c](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to print a particular number of digits after the decimal, you could do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ( )
{
    double d = sqrt(2);
    int digits = 7;
    printf("d=%.*f\n", digits, d);
    return 0;
}
```

The `*` in place of the precision specifier (the digit after the `.`) specifies that the value of the precision appears next in the argument list.  This allows you to print to whatever precision you specify.